# Where can i find CoreNLP Lexicon and how to differentiate between action and stative verbs

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using CoreNLP for semantic network project and i want to know what words does CoreNLP contains and how is it categorized.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you Google search first? http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp-3.5.0/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/BaseLexicon.html

Comment: i searched and did found that class but i do not get how can i get the words already being understood by CoreNLP this class is for training a new set of words like an interface but where is the actual categorization, for instance i want to check whether a verb is an action or state verb how can i know that.